# Explaining gam model output with a reference

Tags: r, inference, references, biostatistics, generalized-additive-model

I'm seeking a good reference to explain the gam model output to colleague. Here is my model.

```
mod1 <- gam(severity ~  s(mean_rh, k = 8) + s(mean_temp, k = 10) + s(mean_ws, k =7) + s(avg_daily_rain, k = 7), family = betar(),  data = dat_seasonal)

summary(mod1)
```

Here is the output:

```
Formula:
disease_severity ~ s(mean_rh, k = 8) + s(mean_temp, k = 10) + 
    s(mean_ws, k = 7) + s(avg_daily_rain, k = 7)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  -0.1687     0.1374  -1.228    0.219

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                    edf Ref.df Chi.sq  p-value    
s(mean_rh)        1.000  1.000   2.76 0.096633 .  
s(mean_temp)      4.231  4.598  74.22  < 2e-16 ***
s(mean_ws)        2.461  2.673  17.53 0.000669 ***
s(avg_daily_rain) 1.000  1.000  49.89  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.847   Deviance explained = 91.8%
-REML = -29.205  Scale est. = 1         n = 37
```

Here is the raw data plot `(left)` and the model output plot `(right)` for the predictor `mean_temp`.

[image]

My collaborator is not aware of GAMS and expects linear/continuous/higher `disease severity` with increasing temperatures OR a bell shaped curve (he doesn't expect less disease at 14 & 16 degree Celsius and higher disease at 12 degree Celcius). Here is his specific comment. "**Does the figure show greater disease severity at 11 and 17 degree Celsius than the temperature in between? That is what I saw in this subfigure and that is against current knowledge and indefensible**."
I need to explain to him `with a reference` that the model has captured the raw data pattern very well, and the whole point behind a GAM is that it models complex behavior between predictors and outcomes. Terms with EDFs higher than one are not supposed to have a singular explanation. The response variable is not linear, DHARMa residuals are fine and the gam.check() output is also good. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[An Introduction to Statistical Learning](https://www.statlearning.com/) covers the principles of GAMs in Section 7.7, with Section 7.7.1 specifically on regression models like yours. I don't think that the particular smooths described there are identical to the `s()` smooths in the `gam()` function of `mgcv` that you used, but the general principle of smooth nonlinear additive modeling is the same.

Note that comparison to the raw data plot can be misleading, as it doesn't take into account the other predictor variables. I'll admit that I didn't at first see how the curve on the right could reasonably have represented the raw data on the left, until I remembered what I was looking at.

As `mean_rh` and `avg_daily_rain` ended up with what seem to be linear fits, you might display the residuals around what you would have predicted based on those linear fits, instead of showing raw data values. That might make the curvilinear association with `mean_temp` more obvious.

Comment: I have already added residuals using `plot(mod1,  rug = TRUE, residuals = TRUE, pch = 1, cex = 1, shade = TRUE, seWithMean = TRUE, shift = coef(mod1)[1])`. Unless you're referring to some other residuals?

Comment: @Ahsk I'm looking for a way to generate something like a "raw data" plot that looks more like your smooth. The raw data plot you show doesn't take into account any of the other variables in the model. If you could take into account the contributions of `mean_rh` and `avg_daily_rain`, that might help. Try plotting the residuals from a simple linear model, with just those two linear predictors, against the `mean_temp` values as an alternative to your simple raw data plot on the left. I suspect that will look more like the smooth on the right.

Comment: Okay, thank you.

Comment: In addition to providing the reference, maybe I should reword my interpretation too to avoid potential conflict. Can I say that, `Overall, increasing temperatures had a positive effect on the response variable, although the effect was not linear. Lower values for response variable were observed between 14-16 degree Celsius`. Thanks very much.

Comment: @Ahsk that doesn't seem to describe the modeled values on the plot on the right, although it _might_ describe the raw values on the left. Modeled values at 12 degrees are about the same as they are at 17. If you are talking about the modeled values, I also wouldn't describe them as "observed." For the modeled values you might say something like: "With other variables taken into account, the model suggests a dip in the response as a function of temperature between about 14 and 16 degrees."

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You could cite the famous [book](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/mono/10.1201/9781315370279/generalized-additive-models-simon-wood) *Generalized Additive Models, An introduction with R.* It include a lot of explanations and several examples.

Comment: Thanks. The book is not available for free. I'm looking for link to somewhat similar example, which is readily available.

Comment: I am sorry. Maybe you can find some way to get it through you institution if you belong to one. It's a pretty standard textbook (the same guy wrote the mgcv package) so it really should be easy to find in any university library.